# Error: this isn't something you can use set on netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to write a piece of code which asks some of the turtles to
calculate 2 parameters, compare them and then if one is lower than the
other, subtracts a characteristic of turtles by 1.
here is the code I wrote but I receive this error: "this isn't something you
can use set on netlogo"

```
        set monthly-electricity-consumption random-float((monthly-electricity-demand * 1.2) - (monthly-electricity-demand * 0.8)) + (monthly-electricity-demand *
0.8)
   ask turtles with [shape = "triangle"] [
      if monthly-electricity-consumption > monthly-electricity-demand [
        set [company-loyalty-level] of self company-loyalty-level - 1]]
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: `set [foo] of ...` is a syntax that used to work in really, _really_ old versions of NetLogo. Wherever you saw that syntax, that's a source you should be very skeptical of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the line

```
set [company-loyalty-level] of self company-loyalty-level - 1]]
```

is the line that generates the error. NetLogo does not allow one turtle to directly set the variables of another turtle by using the `of` construction.  E.g.,

```
ask turtle 1 [set [company-loyalty-level] of turtle 2 (company-loyalty-level - 1)]
```

breaks that rule.  In your case, by using `self`, `turtle 2` and `turtle 1` are the same turtle, but NetLogo will still throw that error.  The line that you want is simply,

```
set company-loyalty-level company-loyalty-level - 1]]
```

Once you are within an `ask`, the variable is understood to be the one associated with the turtle being asked.  The `of self` is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much Charles for your time.

Comment: I had written the code exactly based on the logic you mentioned (which I believe is true) but I ended up generating very strange numbers such as -22576.
I have set the company-loyalty-level for all turtles 10 and during 20 ticks when they are running this procedure, I had expected to end up having a number around 4 or 5 but instead it generates like -22576.
That was why I thought I may have to add "self" in the code!